# Why can't I read message or status code on receiving 409 in response?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using react in front end. Why cant I read data/message sent by the express when the status code is 409 or any 400 status code?

This is how I'm trying to read the response

```
  hSubmit = event => {
    console.log(this.state.checklistName)
    event.preventDefault();
    post.AddChecklistNames(this.state.token,this.state.category,this.state.checklistName)
    .then(res=> {
      if(res.status===201){
        // window.location.reload(true);


      }
      else if(res.status===400||res.status===409||res.status===401||res.status===404||res.status===403){
        console.log(res)
        window.alert(res.data.error)
    }
    this.setState({checklistName:""})
    })
```

What express is sending

```
response.status(409).json({ error: 'there is conflict'})
```

I can't read the error

Comment: Why don't you just try logging the `response` you received without any condition. There might be possibility you are not receiving any of the status code you are using in your `if` condition.

Comment: We actually tried that, but we didn't get anything.

Comment: I suggest you trying `res => { console.log(res) }` and post the response here with your question. If that got blank, then you need to debug whether if you are making any request or server not responding/resolving your request. See `network` tab of your browser to see your eques

Comment: res => { console.log(res) } we tried this but it is showing nothing and in network responses 409 is coming and in console "Error: Request failed with status code 409" this error is coming

Comment: what is your `post.AddChecklistNames`? could you add the code

Comment: import Axios from 'axios';
import URL from '../url';
var post={
 PostData: async function (postData){
    return await Axios.post(`${URL}/login`,postData)
},

AddChecklistNames: async function(token,category,checklistName){
    return await Axios.post(`${URL}/addchecklist`,{
            checklistName: checklistName  
    },{headers:{
        'Authorization' :'Bearer ' + token
    },params:{
        category: category
    }})
},

Answer (score 0):

res is not defined i guess. Try this:

```
.then(res=> {
      if(res.status===201){
        // window.location.reload(true);
      })
.catch (err) {
  console.log(err.response.data)
  window.alert(err.response.data)
}
```

When returning error status code, response is treated as an error, so you should check error.response.data in a catch block

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch error in catch block. In catch block you can see your error response and implement your logic accordingly